# FlutterMap location only updating every second

Tags: flutter, dart, fluttermap, geolocator

I am developing a Flutter application that uses a ticker to reflect location updates on a map. Currently, the location updates on the map occur every second, which results in a jerky user experience. I'd like to achieve smoother location updates for a more fluid visual experience.

**Issue**:

The location data is refreshed every second so it is not smooth and instead jump from one point to another every second.  This is true on simulators and on the real device.

I've checked to see if the behavior changes in indoor vs. outdoor, but it remains consistent. I've insured the ticker is firing consistently every second and the location data seems to be processed as expected.

**Question**:

How can I achieve smoother location updates in Flutter, ideally in real-time or at a higher frequency than once every second? Are there any recommended practices or libraries that could aid in this?

Thanks!

Code summary:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flame/flame.dart';
import 'package:flame/widgets.dart';
... // other imports

class AppScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppScreenState createState() => _AppScreenState();
}

class _AppScreenState extends State<AppScreen> {
  Timer? _updateTimer;
  LatLng _center = LatLng(0, 0);
  Position? _currentPosition;
  final MapController _mapController = MapController();
  ...

  void _updateLocation(Position position) {
    setState(() {
      _center = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    });
  }

  Future<void> _loadSpriteSheet() async {
    ... // loading sprite sheet
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _updateTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (timer) {
      ... // Forcing more frequent marker updates
    });

    ... // Various initialization tasks

    _positionStreamSubscription = Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: locationSettings).listen((Position position) {
      print('Location updated: ${position.latitude}, ${position.longitude}');
      ... // Moving the map controller
    });
  }

  void _checkPermissionAndFetchLocation() async {
    ... // Checking and requesting location permissions
  }

  void _getCurrentLocation() async {
    ... // Fetching and setting the current location
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('My App')),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          FlutterMap(
            ... // Map and layers setup
            children: <Widget>[
              TileLayer(urlTemplate: "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
              if (_currentPosition != null) MarkerLayer(
                markers: [ ... ], // Marker with sprite or icon
              ),
            ],
          ),
          // Other widgets, including sprite widgets and other UI elements
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _positionStreamSubscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
    _ticker?.stop();
  }
}
```

Comment: This was tagged as Flame, but it does not seem to involve Flame? (I removed the tag)

Comment: Some applications use polylines to draw routes/directions and move markers along the polylines at regular intervals.

Comment: May you can try this https://pub.dev/packages/line_animator to move the marker with animation at periodic time.